# Shortcode always at top of content

Tags: php

I have been trying to tweak this but nothing i try really works, this is a plugin i use with a shortcode, and it doesn't matter at what position i place the shortcode on the template, it always appears right at the top just below the header, even when there are images or text above it. Why does this happen?

```
<?php
/*
  Plugin Name: Simple Taxonomy Chain menu
  Plugin URI: http://gifts.wordpress-filter.com/
  Description: Simple taxonomy chain menu shortcode realized by drop-downs. This is gift plugin for WordPress Meta Data Filter & Taxonomies Filter
  Author: realmag777
  Version: 1.0.0
  Author URI: http://www.pluginus.net/
 */

//[mdf_chain_menu taxonomy='product_cat' exclude='' show_count=1 post_slug='product' button_title='Watch It' target='_blank']
//10-11-2014
class MDTF_ChainMenu {

    private $button_title = 'GO!';
    private $target = '_self';

    public function init() {
        add_shortcode('mdf_chain_menu', array($this, 'draw_chain_menu'));
        add_action('wp_head', array($this, 'wp_head'), 1);
        add_action('wp_ajax_mdf_get_chain_select', array($this, 'get_chain_select'));
        add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_mdf_get_chain_select', array($this, 'get_chain_select'));
    }

    public function wp_head() {
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    }

    public function wp_footer() {
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var ajaxurl = "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>";
            jQuery(function () {
                jQuery.fn.life = function (types, data, fn) {
                    jQuery(this.context).on(types, this.selector, data, fn);
                    return this;
                };

                //+++

                jQuery('.mdf_chain_menu').life('change', function () {
                    var cat_id = jQuery(this).val();
                    var _this = this;
                    if (cat_id > 0) {
                        var data = {
                            action: "mdf_get_chain_select",
                            term_id: cat_id,
                            taxonomy: jQuery(this).data('taxonomy'),
                            show_count: jQuery(this).data('show-count'),
                            post_slug: jQuery(this).data('post-slug'),
                            exclude: jQuery(this).data('exclude')
                        };
                        jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function (responce) {
                            jQuery(_this).nextAll('.mdf_chain_menu').remove();
                            jQuery(_this).nextAll('.mdf_chain_menu_posts').remove();
                            jQuery(_this).nextAll('.mdf_chain_menu_post_button').remove();
                            jQuery(_this).after(responce);
                        });
                    } else {
                        jQuery(this).nextAll('.mdf_chain_menu').hide(200, function () {
                            jQuery(this).remove();
                        });
                        jQuery(this).nextAll('.mdf_chain_menu_posts').hide(200, function () {
                            jQuery(this).remove();
                        });
                        jQuery(this).nextAll('.mdf_chain_menu_post_button').hide(200, function () {
                            jQuery(this).remove();
                        });
                    }
                });

                //+++

                jQuery('.mdf_chain_menu_posts').life('change', function () {
                    var link = jQuery(this).val();
                    jQuery(this).nextAll('.mdf_chain_menu_post_button').remove();
                    if (link.length) {
                        jQuery(this).after('<a href="' + link + '" class="button mdf_chain_menu_post_button" target="<?php echo $this->target ?>"><?php echo $this->button_title ?></a>');
                    }
                });

            });
        </script>
        <?php
    }

    //ajax
    public function get_chain_select() {
        $args = array(
            'term_id' => $_REQUEST['term_id'],
            'taxonomy' => $_REQUEST['taxonomy'],
            'show_count' => $_REQUEST['show_count'],
            'post_slug' => $_REQUEST['post_slug'],
            'exclude' => $_REQUEST['exclude']
        );
        $childs_ids = get_term_children($_REQUEST['term_id'], $_REQUEST['taxonomy']);
        if (!empty($childs_ids)) {
            $this->generate_tax_select($args);
        } else {
            $this->generate_post_select($_REQUEST['term_id'], $_REQUEST['taxonomy'], $_REQUEST['post_slug']);
        }

        exit;
    }

    private function generate_post_select($term_id, $taxonomy='category', $post_slug = 'post') {
        $args = array(
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'orderby' => 'title',
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'post_type' => $post_slug,
            'tax_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                    'field' => 'term_id',
                    'terms' => $term_id
                )
            )
        );
        $posts = get_posts($args);
        if (!empty($posts)) {
            ?>
            <select class="mdf_chain_menu_posts input-medium">
                <option value=""><?php _e('Select post', 'meta-data-filter') ?></option>
                <?php foreach ($posts as $post) : ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID) ?>"><?php echo $post->post_title ?></option>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </select>
            <?php
        }
    }

    //shortcode action
    public function draw_chain_menu($args) {
        add_action('wp_footer', array($this, 'wp_footer'), 9999);
        if (!isset($args['term_id'])) {
            $args['term_id'] = 0;
        }
        if (!isset($args['show_count'])) {
            $args['show_count'] = 0;
        }
        if (!isset($args['post_slug'])) {
            $args['post_slug'] = 'post';
        }
        //***
        if (isset($args['button_title'])) {
            $this->button_title = __($args['button_title'], 'meta-data-filter');
        }
        if (isset($args['target'])) {
            $this->target = $args['target'];
        }
        //***
        $this->generate_tax_select($args);
    }

    private function generate_tax_select($args) {
        $terms = $this->get_terms($args);
        if (!empty($terms)):
            ?>
            <select class="mdf_chain_menu" data-taxonomy="<?php echo $args['taxonomy'] ?>" data-exclude="<?php echo $args['exclude'] ?>" data-show-count="<?php echo $args['show_count'] ?>" data-post-slug="<?php echo $args['post_slug'] ?>">
                <option value="0"><?php _e('Choose', 'meta-data-filter') ?></option>
                <?php foreach ($terms as $term) : ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $term['term_id'] ?>"><?php echo $term['name'] ?><?php if ($args['show_count']): ?>&nbsp;(<?php echo $term['count'] ?>)<?php endif; ?></option>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </select>
            <?php
        endif;
    }

    private function get_terms($args) {
        $cats_objects = get_categories(array(
            'orderby' => 'name',
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'style' => 'list',
            'show_count' => 0,
            'hide_empty' => 1,
            'use_desc_for_title' => 1,
            'child_of' => 0,
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'title_li' => '',
            'show_option_none' => '',
            'number' => NULL,
            'echo' => 0,
            'depth' => 0,
            'current_category' => 0,
            'pad_counts' => 0,
            'exclude' => $args['exclude'],
            'taxonomy' => $args['taxonomy'],
            'walker' => 'Walker_Category'));

        $cats = array();
        if (!empty($cats_objects)) {
            foreach ($cats_objects as $value) {
                if ($value->category_parent == $args['term_id']) {
                    $cats[$value->term_id] = array();
                    $cats[$value->term_id]['term_id'] = $value->term_id;
                    $cats[$value->term_id]['name'] = $value->name;
                    $cats[$value->term_id]['count'] = $value->count;
                    /*
                      if($get_childs) {
                      $cats[$value->term_id]['childs'] = $this->assemble_terms_childs($cats_objects, $value->term_id);
                      }
                     * 
                     */
                }
            }
        }
        return $cats;
    }

    private function assemble_terms_childs($cats_objects, $parent_id) {
        $res = array();
        foreach ($cats_objects as $value) {
            if ($value->category_parent == $parent_id) {
                $res[$value->term_id]['term_id'] = $value->term_id;
                $res[$value->term_id]['name'] = $value->name;
                $res[$value->term_id]['count'] = $value->count;
                $res[$value->term_id]['childs'] = $this->assemble_terms_childs($cats_objects, $value->term_id);
            }
        }

        return $res;
    }

}

add_action('init', array((new MDTF_ChainMenu()), 'init'), 1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just print output from a shortcode, you have to return it. Easiest way given your existing code is to use an output buffer. You can modify your `draw_chain_menu()` method like this:

```
//shortcode action
public function draw_chain_menu($args) {
    // previous code omitted...
    ob_start();
    $this->generate_tax_select($args);
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```